# How do I unit test with servlet Filter that access other beans

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot

I am trying to write a unit test for my "OncePerRequestFilter" filter. The problem is the Autowired bean appearing as null inside "public OncePerRequestFilter clientInterceptorFilter()" only in a unit test. The code snippets of my unit test and Filter class is copied below. Can somebody guide me how I can inject the dependent beans in Servlet filter.

My Unit test code goes here

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ImportAutoConfiguration({ RefreshAutoConfiguration.class })
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application.properties")
@Import({ FilterConfig.class, IAuthServiceClient.class, AppConfig.class })
// @TestExecutionListeners({
// DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
// DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class})
public class FilterConfigTest implements AppConstants {

    @MockBean
    private IAuthServiceClient authService;

    @Autowired
    FilterConfig config;

    @Autowired
    ResourceLoader loader;

    @Autowired
    AppConfig appconfig;

    private MockHttpServletRequest  request;
    private MockHttpServletResponse response;
    private MockFilterChain         chain;
    private OncePerRequestFilter    filter;

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
        chain = new MockFilterChain();
        filter = new FilterConfig().clientInterceptorFilter();

    }
    @Test
    public void validTokenTest() throws IOException, ServletException {
        BDDMockito.given(authService.getPrincipal(anyString(), anyList())).willReturn(getStubbedPrincipal());
        this.request.addHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "sometoken");
        this.request.addHeader(XH_AUTH_HEADER, "someauthheader");
        this.filter.doFilter(this.request, this.response, this.chain);
    }
}
```

My Filter class is below. Both "authService" and "config" are null inside "public OncePerRequestFilter clientInterceptorFilter() " function

```
 @Configuration
    public class FilterConfig implements AppConstants {
        @Autowired
        private IAuthServiceClient authService;

        @Autowired
        AppConfig config;

        private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FilterConfig.class);


        @Bean
        public OncePerRequestFilter clientInterceptorFilter() {
            return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
                @Override
                protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                        FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
                    String authorization = Optional.ofNullable(request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)).orElse(null);
                    String xhAuth = Optional.ofNullable(request.getHeader(XH_AUTH_HEADER)).orElse(null);
                    List<String> scopes = config.getscopesAsList();

                    try {
                        Principal principal = authService.getPrincipal(authorization, scopes);
                        if(principal != null) {
                         //do something
                          filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                       throw new NoAuthorizedPrincipalFound(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, INVALID_AUTOIRIZED_PRINCIPAL);

                    }

                }
            };
        }

    }
```

Comment: Ofcourse it is. You are Creating the configuration yourself in the `@Before` method outside of Spring, so it is just a regular method call. But this is hardly a unit test rather an Integrating test. If you want a unit test create the filter yourself, mock the needed dependencies and inject them. Also make it a proper class instead of inlining it like this.

Comment: I think I am not following you. I need to test just filter implementation. @MockBean
  private IAuthServiceClient authService;
trying to mock service. Also, used BDDMockito to mock the response. Are you saying I should remove @Before?

Comment: You want a unit test, but you are rather creating an integration test. Which. You totally bypass by creating your own instance of the configuration to obtain the filter. So which is it you want, an integration or a unit test? If you want a unit test it is easier to create a real class for the filter instead of inlining it.